# How to convert css margin value to pixels with just plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for the simplest and cross browser way to convert html element css margin value to absolute pixels. Say for instance the margin is "auto".
I can't use any js framework.

Comment: So, you want to use change from `margin: auto` to a specific pixel value?

Comment: That's just a particular case, but yes. I want to convert ANY margin to a specific pixel value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `window.getComputedStyle` method:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);
// style.marginLeft
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VxccZ/

**Update**

For IE 8 and older (that do not support this method), use the `currentStyle` property of your element:

```
var style = element.currentStyle;
// style.marginLeft
```

To summarize:

```
var getMarginLeft = function (element) {
  var style;
  if (window.getComputedStyle) { style = window.getComputedStyle(element, null); }
  else { style = element.currentStyle; }

  return style.marginLeft;
};
```

I'm not 100% sure that `currentStyle` features a numeric value for `margin: auto`. You will have to try that yourself. I cannot do that myself on the Mac.

Comment: Nice trick, I haven't seen it anywhere. Is this really crossbrowser?

Comment: IE9+ only. You can use `element.currentStyle` in older versions of IE. Let me update the answer.

Comment: He's looking to convert the value not just retrieve it.

Comment: I'm looking for retrieving the converted-to-px value. I don't really want to change the element. Sorry for the ambiguous question. Ian answer is fine, unfortunately currentStyle does not behave like getComputedStyle. For instance, currentStyle returns "auto" when it is the case.

Comment: @CalebDoucet: getComputedStyle returns a numeric value even for `margin: auto`–i.e. it does the conversion. The problem is in older versions of IE that do not implement the method unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `parseInt()` function to convert strings such as `"125px"` into a number like 125 (trailing non-numeric characters will be ignored)
JavaScript / TypeScript Example:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("someElementId");
var marginTopNumericValue = parseInt(elem.style.marginTop);
document.getElementById("someElementId2") = marginTopNumericValue + "px";
```

Make sure to define the units you're in when reassigning!

Comment: The example given in the question is `auto` not `125px`